# Connect two instances of Identity server with openId

Tags: openid, identityserver4

Is it possible to login into one instance of Identity server using another one?
Specifically: one is public and the other one is behind company firewall.

Example: user from this company wants to login to the public one using its own company credentials (AD for example) using some sort of secure back-channel between these two IDS.

I know this is possible using "Sign-in with External Identity Providers" but I want this to be dynamically configurable - since the number of companies will be growing over time.
What are the options to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I ended up implementing my own OIDC middleware that could accept additional run-time settings rather than using static settings defined at application startup.

It still uses regular OIDC and thus it's a front-channel operation so the 3rd party provider would have to be exposed to the internet and your provider would need direct line of sight too.

To do this I inherited from `OpenIdConnectHandler` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` package and overrode the following virtual methods, replacing references to static config with my runtime provided ones where necessary:

- HandleUnauthorizedAsync
- HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync
- HandleSignOutAsync
- HandleSignOutCallbackAsync

Comment: please, could you share some details?

Comment: What would you like to know? It basically boiled down to taking the standard middleware and overriding the methods I needed to and changed key things (namely client ID and authority URL) to come from the AuthenticationProperties passed into the Challenge method rather than the OpenIdConnectOptions defined in ConfigureServices or Configure.

Comment: Just names of the methods you overridden - to push me in the right direction.